# Python create new column from dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to learn using Python for Data Science and got stuck with the following problem.

Suppose that we have a data frame of the form

[image]

and dictionary of the form

```
    Regions = {“Central Asia”: [“Afghanistan”], 
“Europe”: [“Albania”, “Andorra”], 
“Africa”: [“Algeria”], 
“America”: [“American Samoa”]}
```

I would like to create a new column in the data frame with keys from this dictionary being the entries, like this:

[image]

Is there a good way to do this in Python?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with `dict` where are swapped keys with values:

```
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in Regions.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'Andorra': 'Europe', 'Afghanistan': 'Central Asia',
 'Algeria': 'Africa', 'American Samoa': 'America', 'Albania': 'Europe'}

df['Region'] = df['country'].map(d)
print (df)
          country        Region
0     Afghanistan  Central Asia
1         Albania        Europe
2         Algeria        Africa
3  American Samoa       America
4         Andorra        Europe
```

Answer (score 5):

A one liner using `DataFrame.from_dict` and `df.stack()` (thanks MaxU!):

```
In [8]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Regions, orient='index').stack()\
                     .reset_index(level=0)\
                     .rename(columns={'level_0':'Region',0:'country'})\
                     .reset_index(drop=True)
Out[8]: 
         Region         country
0        Europe         Albania
1        Europe         Andorra
2        Africa         Algeria
3  Central Asia     Afghanistan
4       America  American Samoa
```

Comment: what about: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Regions, orient='index').stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'level_0':'Region',0:'country'}).reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: @MaxU Thank you :) definitely better.